# Identical vectors returning false on Vector3.equals and "=="

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I need to raise the water level in my game. But after playing a while the sound of the water that should be playing when it's raising, isn't stopped.

The output i'm getting in my console:

```
WATERLEVEL NOT AT TARGET
Waterlevel localpos: (1.0, -432.0, -17.4)
target pos: (1.0, -432.0, -17.4)

WATERLEVEL NOT AT TARGET
...(same as previous)
```

This is my method, it moves towards the target and stops the sound when the river is at target position

```
IEnumerator IncreaseWaterLevelCoroutine()
{
    //determine target
    Vector3 target = waterLevel.transform.localPosition;
    target.y += waterStep;

    //prepare
    bool notAtPos = true;
    audioRivierOversteken.Play();

    //start raising water each frame
    while (notAtPos)
    {   
        //raise water level
        float speed = AnimSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        waterLevel.transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(waterLevel.transform.localPosition, target, speed);

        //stop if the waterlevel is at target position
        if (waterLevel.transform.localPosition == target)
        {
            Debug.Log("waterlevel at target");
            StartCoroutine(StopRivierSound(0.5f));
            notAtPos = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("WATERLEVEL NOT AT TARGET");
            Debug.Log("Waterlevel localpos: " + waterLevel.transform.localPosition.ToString());
            Debug.Log("target pos: " + target.ToString());
        }

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: They are not equal. Look closely. First Vector  z is `-147.4`. The other ones z is `-17.4` so they are **not** equal.

Comment: They are not equal in the data you posted, but even if they were this is a really dodgy way to compare a floating point number with a target value. Rounding errors might mean that it is never actually equal. Instead what you should do is to calculate the absolute difference between the components, and check that each of the differences is less than some delta (e.g. 0.0001).

Comment: @MatthewWatson That's fine. Op is comparing two `Vector3` not two floats.  There is an `==` [overload](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) that handles that for `Vector3`.

Comment: @Programmer Yes, but it uses an epsilon of `9.99999944E-11f` which is way too small. See https://answers.unity.com/questions/395513/vector3-comparison-efficiency-and-float-precision.html

Comment: i'm sorry they are both -17.4 edited my question

Comment: @MatthewWatson if i call Vector3.MoveTowards i expect the two positions to be exactly the same, doesn't look dodgy to me

Comment: @MatthewWatson That's true but not likely the problem in this particular case. I did a quick test and the `==` overload is working fine in this case....

Comment: @PrisonMike  Even with your updated answer, there is something wrong in your post. **that should work**. Try this: `Vector3 localpos = new Vector3(1.0f, -432.0f, -17.4f)` then `Vector3 targetpo = new Vector3(1.0f, -432.0f, -18.4f);`. Now, check if they are equals to another: `if (localpos == targetpo)
        {
            Debug.Log("Equals");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Not Equals");
        }` That should be `true`.

Comment: Yes it looks like `Vector3.MoveTowards()` should set the values to be exactly equal if the distance is less than the delta - so this should be working.

Comment: @Programmer ofcourse that will be true; i think the issue is in moveTowards

Comment: What happens if you abandon `==` and use the function `float getSqrDistance(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2)
    {
        return (v1 - v2).sqrMagnitude;
    }` then compare the distance with `if (getSqrDistance(waterLevel.transform.localPosition, target) < 0.001)` ?

Comment: Is it possible that moving elements on a canvas (that contains a canvas scaler) has influence on the moveTowards method? I have no problems if i work with objects that are not on a canvas

Comment: *`Is it possible that moving elements on a canvas (that contains a canvas scaler) has influence on the moveTowards method?`* I wouldn't be surprised, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Do not trust the console output of Vectors. The overridden `ToString()` method on Unity's Vector classes explicitly rounds the contained floats to a single decimal digit of precision.

For example, this code:

```
Vector3 v1 = new Vector3(0.1f, 0, 0);
Vector3 v2 = new Vector3(0.12f, 0, 0);
Debug.Log(v1);
Debug.Log(v2);
Debug.Log(v1 == v2);
```

Prints:

```
(0.1, 0, 0)
(0.1, 0, 0)
false
```

However, a vector of `(0.10001, 0, 0)` will equate as equal (to `v1`), even though `0.1` and `0.10001` will not equate to equal when compared directly.

Comment: this is absolutely correct and i'm aware of it. But what i want to know is why the MoveTowards method stops being exact after a while

Comment: @PrisonMike If you could generate more exact output (by printing the float values directly) that would help figure out what's going on.